# Raspberry pi HDMI Output multiple screens

Tags: hdmi

I want to setup a simple movie player on all 5 tv's I have in a restaurant.

Is there a way I can split the signal coming out from my raspberry ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HDMI splitter/switcher will easily go beyond several hundreds, it might be easier and cheaper to get one RasPi for every TV you have and control them all over a network.

Comment: And you get extra flexibility if you want the screens to not show identical content - you can easily do it

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but watch out for signal loss. In my appartement i have one raspberry feeding 3 TVs, trough 2 splitters. I would say don't go over 50 feet and be sure you don't have a signal booster in your cable. That messes with the splitter signal.

Comment: You are talking about splitter. He want to watch the same signal on all channels

Answer (score 2):

[This device claims](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4-WAY-HD-hub-1080p-1x4-HDMI-Splitter-Amplifier-HDTV-1-3-/190400914230?pt=UK_Computing_Sound_Vision_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item2c54c76336) to rebroadcast 1 signal to 4 TV's - It also says that you can place it at the end of a long cable and it will regenerate the signal.

It might not work with all kinds of devices because of DRM but it should be fine with the Raspberry Pi

[image]

**Update November 2014**

*Please note that you can also get USB HDMI drivers now. Some are 1 USB to 2 HDMI HD display and basic video.
Also there is the new DisplayLink but this is best used on USB 3.0, where you can use 1 USB port to disaply 4 monitors up to 5 display links giving you 20 monitors.
Support on Linux is unknown to me for these but they might be worth researching. I use a USB3.0 on a USB2 port for an extra monitor just for programming on Windows, works great.*